# Galois Group is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $K \subseteq L$ be a Galois field extension with Gal$(L/K) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $L$ is the splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)=(x^2 −a)^2 −b$ 
for elements $a,b \in K$ such that $a \neq 0$, $\sqrt{b} \not \in K$ and $\sqrt{a^2−b} \in K$.

I've tried a direct and contrapositive argument, did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean $(x^2-a)^2-\sqrt{\sqrt b}?$

Comment: Forgive the typos, I've made the appropriate edits.

Comment: You need characteristic not equal to $2$. Then, let $\sigma$ generate the Galois group, and look at the fixed field $E$ of $\sigma^2$, which must be quadratic beneath $L$, so that $L=E(\sqrt z)$ for an appropriate $z\in E$. That is how I would start, anyway.